Error trying to create tests in spark project with scala and maven
I'm trying to create tests in a spark (3.4.1) project using scala (2.12.15) and maven as dependency management, but when I try to run the tests locally i get a lot erros such as:

object scalatest is not a member of package org
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, Suite}

OR

not found: type BeforeAndAfterAll
trait SparkTestingEnv extends BeforeAndAfterAll {

But when I try with mvn clean install the project is build with success bit the test is not included.
What can the problem be?
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <scala.compat.version>2.12</scala.compat.version>
        <scala.version>2.12.15</scala.version>
        <scala.loggin.version>3.7.2</scala.loggin.version>
        <spark.verion>3.4.1</spark.verion>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.verion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.scala-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-logging_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.loggin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.verion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TESTES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mrpowers</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-fast-tests_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
            <version>0.23.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
               <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.3.2</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>compile</goal>
                           <goal>testCompile</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <args>
                               <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                               <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                           </args>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.21.0</version>
               <configuration>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
               <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.0.0</version>
               <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                   <junitxml>.</junitxml>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>test</id>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>test</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.2.4</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>package</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>shade</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <transformers>
                               <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>org.example.Main</mainClass>
                               </transformer>
                           </transformers>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>

</project>

SparkTestingEnv.scala
package org.example

import org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, Suite}

import java.io.File

trait SparkTestingEnv extends BeforeAndAfterAll {
  self: Suite =>

  @transient private var _ss:SparkSession = _
  @transient private lazy val conf = {
    new SparkConf(false)
      .set("spark.ui.enabled", "false")
      .set("spark.testing.memory", "2147480000")
  }

  final def sparkSession: SparkSession = _ss
  final def sparkContext: SparkContext = _ss.sparkContext
  final def sqlContext: SQLContext = _ss.sqlContext

  def clearAll(): Unit = {
    clearSparkCaches()
  }

  def clearSparkCaches(): Unit = {
    _ss.sqlContext.clearCache()
    _ss.sparkContext.getPersistentRDDs.foreach(_._2.unpersist(blocking = true))
  }

  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    super.beforeAll()

    val metastoreDir = new File("metastore_db")
    val warehouseDir = new File("spark-warehouse")

    if (metastoreDir.exists()) JavaUtils.deleteRecursively(metastoreDir)
    if (warehouseDir.exists()) JavaUtils.deleteRecursively(warehouseDir)

    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", System.getenv("HADOOP_HOME"))

    _ss = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("test")
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.sql.extension", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
      .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apace.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
      .getOrCreate()

    _ss.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")
    _ss.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("/tmp")
  }

  override def afterAll(): Unit = {
    super.afterAll()
    _ss.stop()
    _ss = null

    val metastoreDir = new File("metastore_db")
    val warehouseDir = new File("spark-warehouse")

    if(metastoreDir.exists()) JavaUtils.deleteRecursively(metastoreDir)
    if(warehouseDir.exists()) JavaUtils.deleteRecursively(warehouseDir)
  }
}

The test class
for example I only print 1 or tried an assert with two small df
package org.example.generator

import com.github.mrpowers.spark.fast.tests.DataFrameComparer
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.example.SparkTestingEnv
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class TestFunSuite extends FunSuite with SparkTestingEnv with DataFrameComparer {

  lazy val spark: SparkSession = sparkSession
  lazy val sc: SparkContext = sparkContext

  test("Try"){
    print("1")
  }
}

Thanks for the help!
I tried the test with FunSuite, AnyFunSuite or evan create an abstract class like:
abstract class UnitSpec extends AnyFlatSpec with BeforeAndAfter with BeforeAndAfterAll
Then checked all the versions and the build, but I don't know if the build is correct, I copied from other project.
